# Why is mime_content_type() deprecated in PHP?

Tags: php, mime-types, deprecated

I'm just curious to know why [mime_content_type()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mime-content-type.php) is now considered deprecated.

This method for determining the mime type is much easier than the replacement [Fileinfo](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.fileinfo.php) functionality.

Comment: I just looked at the page for mime_content_type in the manual and it doesn't say it's deprecated!  It even includes PHP 7 as a supported version of PHP

Comment: **Its not deprecated** see my answer.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

I guess it's because Fileinfo can [return more information about files](https://www.php.net/manual/en/fileinfo.constants.php).

**EDIT: Here is a replacement hack:**

```
function _mime_content_type($filename) {
    $result = new finfo();
    
    if (is_resource($result) === true) {
        return $result->file($filename, FILEINFO_MIME_TYPE);
    }
    
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Although this is possibly true, the fact remains that it is much harder to configure and takes more effort to use.  Could it not remain un-depricated and just utilize the finfo functions?

Comment: I use a similar hack to determine the file-type of files but firstly use the mime_content_type() method because I have found it to be more reliable across servers.  However i'm still perplexed as to why this method is now deprecated?

Comment: I agree with both your comments, they could have just rewrited the function to rely on the finfo class.

Comment: $result = new finfo(); not work, should be new finfo(FILEINFO_MIME_TYPE);

Comment: @jkjk: It should work, that argument is optional. Plus, I'm pretty sure I have tested this.

Comment: @Josiah the function is not deprecated - see my answer.

Comment: `finfo` not found in latest php

Answer (score 58):

**The method is not deprecated!**

It once was incorrectly marked as deprecated in the manual, but it has been fixed https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=71367 on the 14th of January 2016.
<strike>However, at the moment, it is still incorrectly marked deprecated in the German, Spanish and Chinese manual.</strike>

Feel free to use `mime_content_type()` whenever you like :).

Answer (score 7):

Using [`finfo_file`](http://www.php.net/finfo_file) and [`finfo_open`](http://www.php.net/finfo_open), and [`FILEINFO_MIME_TYPE`](http://www.php.net/fileinfo.constants#constant.fileinfo-mime-type):

```
finfo_file( finfo_open( FILEINFO_MIME_TYPE ), $filename );
```

Here's a small wrapper to cover different PHP environments, derived from [CSSMin.php in MediaWiki 1.20](https://github.com/wikimedia/mediawiki-core/blob/1.22.0/includes/libs/CSSMin.php#L116-L131):

```
function getMimeType( $filename ) {
        $realpath = realpath( $filename );
        if ( $realpath
                && function_exists( 'finfo_file' )
                && function_exists( 'finfo_open' )
                && defined( 'FILEINFO_MIME_TYPE' )
        ) {
                // Use the Fileinfo PECL extension (PHP 5.3+)
                return finfo_file( finfo_open( FILEINFO_MIME_TYPE ), $realpath );
        }
        if ( function_exists( 'mime_content_type' ) ) {
                // Deprecated in PHP 5.3
                return mime_content_type( $realpath );
        }
        return false;
}
```

**EDIT:** Thanks [@Adam](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2311074/adam) and [@ficuscr](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1303868/ficuscr) for clarifying that this function was, in fact, **not deprecated**.

As of MediaWiki 1.30, the above code was essentially changed (back) to:

```
function getMimeType( $filename ) {
        return mime_content_type( $filename );
}
```

Comment: Was not actually deprecated in 5.3, just bad documentation/mistake. In fact support is there for 5.3 > and into 7.0.

Answer (score 6):

Another way is to pass to the constructor constant `FILEINFO_MIME`.

```
$finfo = new finfo(FILEINFO_MIME);
$type  = $finfo->file('path/filename');
```