# mime_content_type() function not defined

Tags: php

I am using the `mime_content_type()` function for file upload, it works fine on localhost however I'm encountering the following error on my live server:

> Fatal error: Call to undefined function mime_content_type()

Comment: http://www.php.net/manual/en/fileinfo.installation.php -> read the first line of the first comment.

Comment: Also note that the function is deprecated: http://php.net/mime_content_type Use http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.fileinfo.php instead.

Comment: Prior to PHP 5.3.0, mime_content_type() was only available via the PECL fileinfo extension - what version of PHP are you running?

Comment: It's documented in the manual. Not deprecated or documented as requiring anything special. But since it doesn't work, I have written my own function.

Answer (score 18):

**Update**:

`mime_content_type()` is no longer deprecated, php7 has support for this function now.

*Earlier version of my answer:*

> `mime_content_type()` is deprecated, probably because [fileinfo][1]
>   can give you those information about the file and more.
>
> You can use finfo() like shown below,
>
> ```
> function _mime_content_type($filename) {
>     $result = new finfo();
>
>     if (is_resource($result) === true) {
>         return $result->file($filename, FILEINFO_MIME_TYPE);
>     }
>
>     return false;
> }
> ```
>
> Ref: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1263977/1161412
>
> [1]: http://php.net/manual/en/class.finfo.php

Comment: finfo is a pecl extension, so won't work if the extension is not installed

Comment: @Okneloper Not anymore, quoating from the installation doc "`This extension is enabled by default as of PHP 5.3.0. Before this time, fileinfo was a PECL extension but is no longer maintained there`" http://php.net/manual/en/fileinfo.installation.php

Comment: yet the installation of 5.6 I tested it on gave me a "Fatal error:  Class 'finfo' not found"

Comment: @Okneloper Is it a windows platform? if it is then you'll need to do this, `Windows users must include the bundled php_fileinfo.dll DLL file in php.ini to enable this extension.`

Comment: no it's not. It's a CentOS with Cpanel. Thanks for the effort though.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.mime-content-type.php "mime_content_type (PHP 4 >= 4.3.0, PHP 5, PHP 7)" (I.E. not deprecated)

Comment: @HoldOffHunger It was marked as deprecated on the same documentation page at the time I wrote this answer. I guess they are supporting it now in php7.

Answer (score 16):

You must have the `mime_magic` extension on. Check your php.ini and look in phpinfo(). By the way this function has been deprecated as the PECL extension [Fileinfo](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.fileinfo.php) provides the same functionality (and more) in a much cleaner way.

> Windows users must include the bundled php_fileinfo.dll DLL file in
> php.ini to enable this extension.
>
> The libmagic library is bundled with PHP, but includes PHP specific
> changes. A patch against libmagic named libmagic.patch is maintained
> and may be found within the PHP fileinfo extensions source.

[Read more](http://www.php.net/manual/en/fileinfo.installation.php)

Comment: Recently, the php_fileinfo extension

Answer (score 4):

## PHP 8

1. Edit your `php.ini` file and uncomment `extension=fileinfo`.
2. Restart your HTTP server (e.g. Apache).
3. `echo mime_content_type($path_absolute.$file);//Outputs: application/pdf`

## PHP 7

1. Edit your `php.ini` file and uncomment `extension=php_fileinfo.dll`.
2. Restart your HTTP server (e.g. Apache).
3. `echo mime_content_type($path_absolute.$file);//Outputs: application/pdf`

Comment: Thank you everywhere just saying it has been deprecated but after adding this gets resolved.

Comment: @AazadRkhan Who is saying `mime_content_type()` is deprecated? Certainly not the documentation! https://www.php.net/mime_content_type

Comment: most of the link are saying **mime_content_type()** get deprecated. but after some research I found in here

Answer (score 1):

If you are on shared hosting, chances are that the [*fileinfo* PHP extension](https://www.php.net/manual/en/fileinfo.installation.php) is either not enabled or installed.

In the case where it's not enabled, navigate to the **Software** section of [CPanel](https://cpanel.net) (consult documentation of your control panel if you're not using CPanel) and click **Select PHP Version** (or something related to that) and enable the extension by checking its box and saving your action.

If it's not installed, the extension won't be part of the PHP extensions at **`cPanel > Software > Select PHP Version > Extensions`**, edit your `php.ini` file and uncomment `extension=php_fileinfo.dll` if you're on Windows. Consult your hosting provider's docs if any of these don't work.

Answer (score -1):

I changed my php version from 7.1 to 5.6 it works for me

Answer (score -2):

Likely missing \php\extras\magic.mime file.