# mime_content_type() support in php

Tags: php, apache, mime-types, wampserver

I am trying to install an instance of forma.lms on WAMP Server running on Windows 8 (not sure how relevant the OS might be).

As with most PHP frameworks, there is a checklist in the installation process which displays a green affirmation for all the present required features. I have one red rejection in the form of 
mime_content_type() support: **OFF**

I checked my wamp settings and looked in the listed php and apache features and neither had any mime feature that was either not ticked or applicable to the missing module.

What pray tell, might I do to free this up?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I'm not sure it's the PHP version being the issue, but what is your version just to be sure? Also, the function is deprecated -[`mime_content_type()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mime-content-type.php)

Comment: Also, you need the `mime_magic` extension on - [Read More](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14809304/2518525)

Comment: @Darren the function is not deprecated, it was just [a bug in the docs](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=71367)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The mime_content_type error is due to it not being available in your PHP build (it has been deprecated for some time now).  But you could create that function yourself: http://php.net/mime_content_type

If you are using the latest version of the class, you can also override the mime type by passing 'Content-Type' => 'your-mime-type' to putObject()'s $requestHeaders.  See: https://github.com/tpyo/amazon-s3-php-class#uploading-objects

There is an update in the works to allow custom mime lookup callbacks too.

Comment: Yeh, after some more research, I realized that was the cause. I successfully deployed it on my bluehost hosted site space, so I guess, I'll mod the local server for local purposes

Comment: `mime_content_type` never was deprecated. It was just [a bug in the docs](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=71367).