# Extension validation in php

Tags: php, file-upload

I've been trying and retrying at this code trying to get the file extension and conditionally check against it, but due to the files placement in flow I can't see what's going into $ext.

Can anyone pinpoint what is going wrong here? It's just manipulating the uploads file for dropzone.js.

```
if (!empty($_FILES)) {

    $tempFile = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];          //3             

    $targetPath = dirname( __FILE__ ) . $ds. $storeFolder . $ds;  //4

    $targetFile =  $targetPath. $_FILES['file']['name'];  //5

    $ext = end(explode(".", $_FILES['file']['tmp_name']));

    if(filesize($tempFile) < 6000000 and $ext == "png"){
        move_uploaded_file($tempFile,$targetFile); //6
    }

}
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "due to the files placement in flow"

Comment: dont base this all on the file extension. I could rename a php file to png, upload it, and then possibly run it from your uploads directory. find out the mimetype and then validate using that. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23287341/how-to-get-mime-type-of-a-file-in-php-5-5

Answer (score 0):

You are using tmp_name variable to get extension which will always give you file with .tmp extension.

In place of

```
$ext = end(explode(".", $_FILES['file']['tmp_name']));
```

Use this :

```
$ext = end(explode(".", $_FILES['file']['name']));
```

Update :- But it is better to validate the file type by checking its mime time(as said by @castis), as some user might rename its file with some extension and upload it.

Below is a code sample to validate a text file, you can use similar method to validate image type.

```
$file_type =  mime_content_type($_FILES['img']['tmp_name']);

if($file_type == 'text/plain'){
    echo "file type is text";
}
?>

<form action="#" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <input type="file" name="img">
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Comment: Also you can find file extenstion using  $ext = pathinfo($_FILES['file_name']['name'],PATHINFO_EXTENSION);