# getimagesize() vs finfo_file() the exact same for detecting mime type?

Tags: php, gd, mime-types, fileinfo, getimagesize

Are these functions doing the same checks to detect the mime type of a file? Are there any benefits in choosing one over the other (i.e. terms of reliability/security)?

Answer (score 3):

They are for different purpose, so you may use in they specific scope.
I'm prefer use `finfo` for the first check of the reliability of file if I don't know its origin

> getimagesize — Get the size of an image

Which **also** can gather the meta segment for JPG APP and **presume** to detect the **image mime**

And

> finfo_file — Return information about a file

Will get you the meta info from the file

**A**s you marked GD, you may be interacting with images only(?). So you may use `getimagesize()`, which seem to return the mime type of file independent of its  extension, being a +1 on security, but probably limited by PHP supported images types.

My PHP 5.6.4 has:

```
    [IMAGETYPE_GIF] => 1
    [IMAGETYPE_JPEG] => 2
    [IMAGETYPE_PNG] => 3
    [IMAGETYPE_SWF] => 4
    [IMAGETYPE_PSD] => 5
    [IMAGETYPE_BMP] => 6
    [IMAGETYPE_TIFF_II] => 7
    [IMAGETYPE_TIFF_MM] => 8
    [IMAGETYPE_JPC] => 9
    [IMAGETYPE_JP2] => 10
    [IMAGETYPE_JPX] => 11
    [IMAGETYPE_JB2] => 12
    [IMAGETYPE_SWC] => 13
    [IMAGETYPE_IFF] => 14
    [IMAGETYPE_WBMP] => 15
    [IMAGETYPE_JPEG2000] => 9
    [IMAGETYPE_XBM] => 16
    [IMAGETYPE_ICO] => 17
    [IMAGETYPE_UNKNOWN] => 0
    [IMAGETYPE_COUNT] => 18
```

**O**n the other hand, I suggest you use `finfo`, to gatter real meta info of your file.

`finfo` do not read other thing than the headers, `getimagesize` can also return some markers and also extra info (extra computation), **image specific** info.

**L**ets check:

Having this simple non standar function:

```
function displayInfo($path, $info = FILEINFO_MIME_TYPE ) {

        $imageinfo = array();
        $getimagesize = array();

        $finfo = new finfo($info);
        $finfo_mt = $finfo->file($path);

        print_r(getimagesize($path, $imageinfo));
        print_r($imageinfo);
        print_r($finfo_mt);
    }
```

You may use $info=FILEINFO_MIME to return Type and Encoding for **safe** reading a file. So,

`display('file.php');`  will output

```
Array
(
)
text/x-php
```

`display('image.png.hide');`  and
`display('image.png');`  will output

```
Array
(
    [0] => 31
    [1] => 31
    [2] => 3
    [3] => width="31" height="31"
    [bits] => 8
    [mime] => image/png
)
Array
(
)
image/png
```

and,
`display('image.jpg');`  will output

```
Array
(
    [0] => 206
    [1] => 206
    [2] => 2
    [3] => width="206" height="206"
    [bits] => 8
    [channels] => 3
    [mime] => image/jpeg
)
Array
(
    [APP0] => JFIF
    [APP13] => Photoshop 3.08BIMgldeLs_Kr6L1Vvu73FGOs(bFBMD01000ac1030000b1060000ad0b00006f0c0000800d0000fe11000011180000bf180000c8190000ef1a0000d2240000
    [APP2] => [REMOVED UTF CHARS FOR stackoverflow]
)
image/jpeg
```

Hope to be pointed on your question.

Answer (score -2):

well there are basically two ways of finding the mime types of the files... one is mime_content_type and the other is file info... 
you can refer the urls bellow :

http://php.net/manual/en/function.finfo-file.php

http://php.net/manual/en/function.mime-content-type.php

mime_content_type is now deprecated .. file info method is for latest php versions... file info requires fileinfo extension to be enabled on the server...

Comment: Thanks for this response, but this is not what I was asking?

Comment: According to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1263957/why-is-mime-content-type-deprecated-in-php#answer-39676272), `mime_content_type()` is not depreciated; the depreciation message was a [bug in the documentation](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=71367) that has since been fixed.