# php unexpected mime type docx

Tags: php, mime-types

I have a form to handle file uploads of restricted types (pdf, docx, etc)  I had someone tell me they couldn't upload a docx.  Oddly, other people can.  So, I had the form show me the $mime_type for this particular file

`$mime_type = mime_content_type($_FILES['input_name']['tmp_name']);`

and it came back with this:

application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.documentapplication/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document

appears to be doubled up!?  I ran some other docx files through it and they call came back as expected.  Please can someone tell me what would cause this file type to be double?

Thank you

Comment: You should ask what their browser and version they are using is and the maybe the document as well if you can't reproduce otherwise.

Comment: Thank you.  I did get the file from them, and ran the test using it (sorry if that wasn't clear enough above).  Latest chrome browser version.  File looks like a normal docx, but if I create other docx files I do not have the same issue.

Comment: Okay, then whatever `mime_content_type()` is doing is putting it twice in there or do you find such logic in your application somewhere? Otherwise I'll link to a question from SO with `Fileinfo` as an alternative.

Comment: See Fileinfo answer from here: [unrelated mime\_content\_type() question, but answer might help you](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1263957/why-is-mime-content-type-deprecated-in-php)

Comment: Thank you.  I tried Fileinfo, with the same result.  This docx file shows "application/vnd.openxmlformats..." twice.  Other docx files just once, as expected.  I have added the double version as an accepted MIME type and it now allows the file to be uploaded.  No idea what's going on, but thank you for your time.

Comment: Okay nice, so at least this workaround exists. Glad to help 