# PHP different file type of same file in different browser

Tags: php, file-upload

I am developing application in PHP which takes video file. I am giving serverside validation (`$_FILES['file']['type']`) that receive only .MP4 files.

If i upload any MP4 file from Firefox browser then file type is 'application/octet-stream' and if i upload same file from Google Chrome then file type is `'video/mp4'`.

If i upload any FLV file from Firefox then file type is also `'application/octet-stream'` then how can i identify the file type of that video?

Comment: By extension...or using the http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.finfo-file.php functions on the $_FILES['file']['tmp_name']

Comment: Never ever trust the `type` sent by the browser. It is fairly easy to spoof the mime type of an exe file as something else.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried using the file info library? `finfo_file()`

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.finfo-file.php

it has a sister function `mime_content_type()`

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mime-content-type.php

Comment: Using that function it should come back as 'video/mp4', but it is only available once it has been uploaded.

Comment: Oh, and if you aren't able to get access to the library on your install (or its not available) this may be useful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/652002/detecting-mime-type-in-php

Comment: "but it is only available once it has been uploaded" ...once you have access to $_FILES var, the file is already on the server in a temporary location ;)

Comment: Yes, i was only clarifying for him. =) Thank you!