# What is the mime_types to upload csv file?

Tags: file, csv, symfony-1.4

I try `'text/csv'` and `'text/plain'` but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 2):

Read my issue I had this week: [Detecting a mime type fails in php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16190929/detecting-a-mime-type-fails-in-php). Apparently mime type detection is not reliable. While detecting a mime-type of a file you may get a false-positive, for example when the string `C F` is present in your file. `C F` in my case was detected as some byte-sequence belonging to Fortran and thus my mime-type was detected as `text/x-fortran`. From experience I know that a solution for csv files is to enquote every cell. But this of course does not work when you have to validate user data.

Comment: Depends on our needs. I found that mime-type checking is only useful for displaying file type icons etc. When making uploaded files available in some public folder just make sure you set the correct permissions, e.g. don't make them executable and make sure you notify other users of downloading user uploaded files. I also found that when processing uploaded CSV-files, e.g. store contents in a database mime-type checking is not necessary. The only need is to check if either a text/* file (source) or an application/* (binary) file is uploaded, since only source files can be processed.

Comment: Also I must add, when processing assume that the contents of the CSV file adheres to the ABNF syntax of a CSV-file: http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4180.txt. If not; don't accept the user-uploaded file and don't process it.

Comment: The solution I find is to create a postValidator in which I get the path of the file and I do a test to check if is a csv file or not and it works fine