# CSV Upload - mime types

Tags: symfony1, symfony-1.4, symfony-forms

Hi I'm trying to upload a CSV file using the following form code:

```
$this->widgetSchema ['file'] = new sfWidgetFormInputFile();

$this->setValidator('file', new sfValidatorFile(array(
            'required'        => true,
            'path'            => sfConfig::get('sf_upload_dir') . '/properties/csv',
            'mime_categories' => array('csv' => array('text/csv', 'application/csv', 'application/excel', 'application/vnd.ms-excel', 'application/vnd.msexcel')),
            'mime_types'      => 'csv'
)));
```

In my action I have:

```
     if($request->isMethod('post'))
     {
         $propertyCsvForm->bind($request->getParameter($propertyCsvForm->getName()), $request->getFiles($propertyCsvForm->getName()));
         if($propertyCsvForm->isValid())
         {
             $this->getUser()->setFlash('success-csv', 'The CSV was successfully imported.');
         } else {
            $this->getUser()->setFlash('error-csv', 'The CSV could not be imported.');
         }
     }
```

When I try to upload a CSV I always get an error, which is the mime type is incorrect

`Invalid mime type (text/plain).`

Any ideas why?

Thanks

Comment: Does my post help you? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16190929/detecting-a-mime-type-fails-in-php.
Mime type detection is unreliable.

Comment: You should also accept plain file (ie; mime_types `text/plain`) as csv file. What if you create a new file with your editor, save it as a csv, and want to upload it? It will have `text/plain`. It will be better to validate (using a post validator) the **content** of your csv (with `fgetcsv` etc ..), like checking if you have XX number of columns, named with this term, etc .. rather than checking the mime_types.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and I solved it creating a `postValidator` in which I get the path of the file and I do a test to check if is a csv file or not and it works fine

```
class sfValidatorCSV extends sfValidatorSchema
{
    protected function configure($options = array(), $messages = array())
    {
        parent::configure($options, $messages);
    }

    protected function doClean($values)
    {
        $file = $values['file'];

        if(empty($file)==false)
        {
            $filename = $file->getOriginalName();

            $path = pathinfo($filename);

            if($path['extension']!="csv")
            {
                throw new sfValidatorError($this, 'Invalid extension.');
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And you call it at the end of your form like this:

```
$this->mergePostValidator(new sfValidatorCSV());
```

Comment: What if the csv file is actually a zip file? Boum :)

Comment: The file will always be a CSV

Comment: So remove `'mime_types' => 'csv'`

Comment: Take a file `test.zip`, rename it to `test.csv`, upload it. Done. Your code *only* check the extension in the filename, not the content.

Comment: Yes, must be add a test to check if it is a zip file, with `finfo_file` function

Comment: You should never validate a file only by the extension. It's not really validating if the file is a csv, it is only checking that the file name ends with `.csv`