# Codeigniter csv file type shows as text/x-fortran

Tags: php, python, codeigniter, csv

I'm using codeigniter upload class and I'm trying to upload a csv file.

Here is my PHP code :

```
public function upload(){
    $config['upload_path']      = './csv/';
    $config['allowed_types']    = 'csv';
    $config['max_size']         = 10240;
    $this->upload->initialize($config);
    if (!$this->upload->do_upload('file')){
        echo "<pre>"; 
        print_r($this->upload->data()); 
        echo "</pre>"; 
        die();
        $this->session->set_flashdata('upload_error', $this->upload->display_errors());
        redirect('/Customers');
    }else{
        $this->session->set_flashdata('upload_success', 'Customer list successfully uploaded!');
        redirect('/Customers');
    }   
}
```

when I upload my csv file I get :

```
Array
(
    [file_name] => mayfile.csv
    [file_type] => text/x-fortran
    [file_path] => /home/public_html/....
    [file_ext] => .csv
    [file_size] => 7842
    [is_image] => 
    [image_width] => 
    [image_height] => 
    [image_type] => 
    [image_size_str] => 
)
```

The type should be text/csv not text/x-fortran why is that happening?

This is a preview of the csv file data I have uploaded:
[[image: CSV uploaded[1]]

Thank you

Answer (score 4):

I believe this is a duplicate of:
[Detecting a mime type fails in php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16190929/detecting-a-mime-type-fails-in-php)

In it, the answer states:

> Apparently, it scans the start of the file looking for lines that begin with a single C letter plus spaces, which seem to be a Fortran style comment. Thus the false positive:

```
somecolumn;
C F;
```

I would recommend reading that answer for further instructions. In this particular case, I'd recommend checking the extension if the mime is returned as Fortran to ensure it's not a CSV. Unfortunately there isn't a cleaner way that I know of.