# Add MIME type knowledge to PHP

Tags: php, mime

I know of the UNIX command `file` to detect the mime type of a file, which I can execute via PHP (like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/652002/detecting-mime-type-in-php)):

```
$content_type = exec("file -bi " . escapeshellarg($filepath));
```

And I am also aware of

```
$fi = new finfo();
echo $fi->file($filename, FILEINFO_MIME_TYPE) . PHP_EOL;
```

and

```
echo mime_content_type($filename) . PHP_EOL;
```

Both PHP built-in solutions produce the same output. However, the Linux `file` command knows some formats more.

AMR audio files were reported as `application/octet-stream` with all three methods. Then I added the file magic to the database of the `file` command:

```
$ cat /etc/magic
0   string  #!AMR\n Adaptive Multi-Rate Audio Codec
!:mime  audio/amr

$ file -bi test115.amr 
audio/amr; charset=binary
```

However, PHP still reports `application/octet-stream`.

I thought the PHP-builtin and `file` use the same database somehow. How can I train PHP to know the MIME type of an AMR file?

Answer (score 1):

PHP seems to use their own, bundled database for fileinfo lookups; you can override this behaviour by either adding the second parameter to the `new finfo` call, or by setting the `MAGIC` env var.

From the docs:

> Note:
>   Generally, using the bundled magic database (by leaving magic_file and the MAGIC environment variables unset) is the best course of action unless you specifically need a custom magic database.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.finfo-open.php